# Black box when transitioning from custom large title nav bar to regular nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

There is a strange thing that occurs when I transition from one view with a large title navigation bar that has been customized with a different shadow to another view that has a regular height navigation bar. You can see the black box in this gif

[image: Strange black background in transition gif]

Here is the related code that lives in both the main view and detail view

Main view:

```
func setupNavBar() {
        // Set the nav bar to have large titles. This is on a per instance basis
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.87, green:0.87, blue:0.87, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
```

Detail view:

```
func setupNavBar() {
        self.title = colorPalette?.title
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.87, green:0.87, blue:0.87, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
```

There is no view that has a black background in interface builder either. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Check ✓ Extended Edges `Under Opaque Bars` on storyboard, or set

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Or set the navigationBar's translucent to true.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Instad of

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

use

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```